# How to use events is jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins

Sorry this is my first time trying to create a plugin, so I might be way off. I have read the docs but got confused, and I decided to learn by trying....

I am trying to make a simple form validation plugin

```
(function($){
    $.fn.bluevalidate = function(options){

        var defaults = {
            errorMsg : 'You have an error',
            required : ''
        };

        var opt = $.extend(defaults,options);

        return this.each(function(index,element){
           var e = $(element);

           if(opt.required!='')
           {
                e.bind('blur',function(){
                    alert("required is here");
                });
           }
           else
           {
                alert("NOOOOOOOOO");
           }
        });
    };
```

})( jQuery )

And I am calling it like

```
$('#username').bluevalidate({
     required:'This field is required';
})
```

I want to get the alert when the user clicks off the field, but as you can guess, my method isn't working, please tell me what I am doing wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an extra `;` in there, it should be:

```
$('#username').bluevalidate({
  required:'This field is required'
})
```

When declaring an object literal, your properties should not be followed by a `;` (you should however have a `,` *between* properties).  This is the main issue:

```
  required:'This field is required'; //the ; shouldn't be here
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/EPvzd/).

Comment: thanks, on a side note, may I ask what problem I might face if I use e.blur(function(){}) instead of bind?

Comment: @Bluemagica - no problems, it's just a shortcut, they're added for a number of events.